# elfファイル中の文字列リテラルの表示

Tags: linux

elfファイルの.rodataセクションに含まれる文字列リテラルのみを全て表示する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3):

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata FILE
```

でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

**readelf**

```
$ readelf -p \.rodata ELF
```

**objcopy + strings**

```
$ objcopy ELF /dev/null --dump-section \.rodata=/dev/stdout | strings -n1
```

--dump-section というオプション名の通りに、指定セクションの内容をそのまま出力して、strings コマンドで printable characters のみを取り出します。ただ、printable characters とは言っても 7-bit byte character(ASCII, ISO 8859, etc.) のみですので、UTF-8 の様な 8-bit byte character は除去されてしまいます。

```
$ echo 'Hello World おはよう、世界' | strings
Hello World
```

なお、GNU binutils の strings コマンドの場合には 8-bit byte character も取り出す事ができます。

```
$ strings --version
GNU strings (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.27.51.20161220
$ echo 'Hello World おはよう、世界' | strings --encoding=S
Hello World おはよう、世界
```